# How to indent HTML output using GULP JADE

Tags: html, gulp, pug

I´m using JADE and GULP to compile HTML but this settings output HTML minifield and I need that this HTML indent

How can I configure this to output HTML indent??

This is my gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('jade', function() { 
  return gulp.src(config.jade)
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/dist'))
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can simply do this:

```
.pipe(jade({ pretty: true }))
```

Comment: Wow. . .  Thank you idbehold